# Does inequality sign remain same?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let say we have inequality $y< x^{-1}$. We take log on both side And we get
[log( y ).... -1 \log(x)].
What will be the inequality sign in between. Will it remain same or flip ?

Comment: hint: $\ln\nearrow$ on $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: $$a<b\iff \log a<\log b$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $0<y<x^{-1}$, applying $\log$ to both sides *does not change the inequality* because the function $\log$ on $(0,+\infty)$ is a *monotonically (strictly) increasing function*. So it stays: $\log y<\log x^{-1}=-\log x$.